# What is the most common proporty that ensure positive autocovariance for stochastic processes?

Tags: time-series, correlation, autocorrelation, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I have discovered a method to efficiently compute variances of statistics of Markov chains and time series, and now I want to find applications. The method does however require that the autocovariance

1. does only depend on observations $X_i$ and $X_j$ through the difference $|i-j|$ for all $i,j$, and
2. is non-negative.

Point 2. occurs often, and it'd be interesting to learn why that is the case. So my question then: in the literature, what is the most common conditions that imply non-negative autocovariance?